# spider is not crawling webpage

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Hi everyone I'm trying to run this python [code](https://gist.github.com/razaulhaq/d39ec325d1f075b6572b) but it's not giving me required output which is I want to print all links available on body of giving webpage but it is giving this [output](https://gist.github.com/razaulhaq/63f73d379af25192baa4) instead, help me
Thanks

Comment: You need to fix the question. What output are you looking for? What's missing that's not in the current output

Answer (score 0):

In order to print the log, you have to use [logging](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html#logging) in your spider with

```
self.logger.debug('%s', response.url)
```

But your spider is wrong, because the parse method have to return an iterable, read the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.parse) for more helps